# How to Fill content according to selection excel?

Tags: excel, function, validation

i have a list made in the grey cell , it has two options "adv" or "dis" each choice has contents , i want to fill the selected cells with the contents of the chosen option[image]

Comment: There is no problem-statement, no question and no details to help us debug your current formula/code. Please refer to [ask] a question with a [mcve] and edit the post accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So use an if() like so, entered in cell L2:

```
=if(H$4="dis",J2,k2)
```

Then drag down, this assumes that H4 is the control for all cells.

Comment: Thank you so much  i wish i had enough appreciations to rank your answer up